# Computed Property not calculated when passing as parameter in $http.post in AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am creating some object in jQuery which also contains some computed properties. I am sending that object to my web API service where this object is defined as class object. All properties from $scope variable set properly except computed variable where it appears as NULL mean their values not calculated when send as part of $http.post method. Please see my code.

jQuery code

```
$scope.EstimationEfforts = {

        //Total no. of apps distribution
        TotalAppsDistributionNumbers: [
            {
                Description: "Number of No Issue Apps",
                Value: function () { return ($scope.Total_No_Apps * $scope.CalculationAsssumptions.ExprienceBasedAssumptions[0].Ratio) / 100 }
            },
            {
                Description: "Number of Apps with vendor upgrade",
                Value: function () { return ($scope.Total_No_Apps * $scope.CalculationAsssumptions.ExprienceBasedAssumptions[1].Ratio) / 100 }
            },
            {
                Description: "Number of Bespoke Apps not Requiring remediation",
                Value: function () { return ($scope.Total_No_Apps * $scope.CalculationAsssumptions.ExprienceBasedAssumptions[2].Ratio) / 100 }
            },
            {
                Description: "Number of Bespoke Apps Requiring remediation",
                Value: 12
            }
        ]}
```

Now I am sending this variable in post call as shown below..

```
var EffortModel = $scope.EstimationEfforts;

    $http.post('/EffortEstimate/GenerateExcel', $scope.EstimationEfforts).success(function (data) {
        alert(data);        
    });
```

On server side my sample code is like this...

```
public class EffortModel
{
    public List<AppDetails> TotalAppsDistributionNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class AppDetails
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float? Value { get; set; }       
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenerateExcel(EffortModel objEffortModel)
    {
        float? ss = objEffortModel.TotalAppsDistributionNumbers[0].Value;
        return Json(ss, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

On server all Description appears properly but Values (computed properties) appearing NULL. where as it contains values on client side before call goes to server side which I can see through firebug it read as Value() means act as function.

How I can get their values on server side?

Comment: You're trying to post a `function` which does not have a corresponding _.Net_  type.

Comment: I fail to see the `jQuery` code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send `function` objects as parameters in your POST method, because there's no corresponding .Net type to which it can be converted. The `function` stored in the `Value` property will not get automatically evaluated before the data gets sent.

I'll assume that you use this object inside your *angularjs* controller. If this is true, you should create another "companion" object, which stores the functions and the original object should store the computed values:

```
 var tmpTotalAppsDistributionNumbers = [
        {
            Description: "Number of No Issue Apps",
            Value: function () { return ($scope.Total_No_Apps * $scope.CalculationAsssumptions.ExprienceBasedAssumptions[0].Ratio) / 100 }
        },
        {
            Description: "Number of Apps with vendor upgrade",
            Value: function () { return ($scope.Total_No_Apps * $scope.CalculationAsssumptions.ExprienceBasedAssumptions[1].Ratio) / 100 }
        },
        {
            Description: "Number of Bespoke Apps not Requiring remediation",
            Value: function () { return ($scope.Total_No_Apps * $scope.CalculationAsssumptions.ExprienceBasedAssumptions[2].Ratio) / 100 }
        },
        {
            Description: "Number of Bespoke Apps Requiring remediation",
            Value: 12
        }
    ]}

$scope.EstimationEfforts = {
    //Total no. of apps distribution
    TotalAppsDistributionNumbers: [
    ]
}

//this should be called just before making the post request
for (var i = 0; i < tmpTotalAppsDistributionNumbers.length; i++){ 
    var val = 0;
    if (typeof tmpTotalAppsDistributionNumbers[i].Value === "function") {
        val = tmpTotalAppsDistributionNumbers[i].Value();
    } else {
        val = tmpTotalAppsDistributionNumbers[i].Value;
    }

    $scope.EstimationEfforts.TotalAppsDistributionNumbers.push(
        {
            Description: tmpTotalAppsDistributionNumbers[i].Description,
            Value: val
        }
    );
}
```

If you're not going to use this object before posting, you can always just use the computation without wrapping in inside a function.